# Is it possible to enforce encrypted SMTP for certain recipients?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, encryption, smtp

I'm trying to understand how to send encrypted email from an ASP.NET application using an SMTP server set up on IIS. Apologies in advance if I'm not being clear - I'm fundamentally a programmer and my understanding of email is limited.

I know that the SMTP server can be configured to insist on TLS/SSL encryption. What I'm not clear about is how this works with the `EnableSsl` property of `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()` and the implications when sending to recipients which don't support encryption.

My goal is to ensure that emails sent to certain recipients are always encrypted, but I don't want emails to fail when sent to other recipients whose receiving SMTP servers don't support encrypted messages.

Is it possible therefore to use SSL conditionally in my scenario based on the intended recipient?

Answer (score 0):

Usually mail is delivered to a mail server local to the sender, i.e. your "SMTP server set up on IIS". This mail server then looks up which servers are responsible for the recipients domain and forwards your mail to these servers.

While you can control how the connection is done between your application and your SMTP server (i.e. TLS or not) you have no control how this mail is forwarded from there on. But modern mail servers typically use TLS if the remote mail server offers support for it and fall back if TLS is not supported by the remote server.

Comment: Thank you for this. When you say "you have no control how this mail is forwarded from there on", is that talking from a programming perspective? I believe it's possible to configure an SMTP server to always use TLS so I'm curious about what happens in this setup when TLS is not supported by the remote server. I appreciate we're moving into Server Fault territory here...

Comment: @getsetcode: I mean that as the sender you have no control. The sender usually has no access to the configuration of the SMTP server. But even have you access to your own SMTP server there can be multiple hops until the recipient is reached and the server administrator can only control the behavior of its own server, i.e. only the next hop.